# use of #define in c

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define d 10+10

int main()
{
    printf("%d",d*d);
return 0;
}
```

I am new to the concept of macros.I found the output for the above program to be 120.What is the logic behind it?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `cpp source.c` to see how is expanded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macros are replaced *literally*. Think of search/replace. The compiler sees your code as `10+10*10+10`.

It is common practice to enclose macro replacement texts in parentheses for that reason:

```
#define d (10 + 10)
```

This is even more important when your macro is a function-like macro:

```
#define SQ(x) ((x) * (x))
```

Think of `SQ(a + b)`...

Answer (score 5):

```
10+10*10+10 == 10 + 100 + 10
```

Is that clear?

Answer (score 1):

`d*d` expands into `10+10*10+10`. Multiplication comes before addition, so 10 + 100 + 10 = 120.

In general, `#define` expressions should always be parenthesized: `#define d (10+10)`

Answer (score 1):

A macro is a nothing more than a simple text replacement, so your line:

```
printf("%d",d*d);
```

becomes

```
printf("%d",10+10*10+10);
```

You could use a `const` variable for more reliable behaviour:

```
const int d = 10+10;
```

Answer (score 1):

The macro is expanded as is.
Your program becomes

```
/* declarations and definitions from headers */

int main()
{
    printf("%d",10+10*10+10);
return 0;
}
```

and the calculation is interpreted as

```
10 + (10 * 10) + 10
```

Always use parenthesis around macros (and their arguments when you have them)

```
#define d (10 + 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#define
```

preprocessor directive substitute the first element with the second element.

Just like a "find and replace"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about #include but in C# #define is used at the top to define a symbol. This allows the coder to do things like

```
#define DEBUG

string connStr = "myProductionDatabase";

#if DEBUG
    connStr = "myTestDatabase"
#edif
```

Answer (score 0):

`10+10*10+10 = 20 + 100 = 120`

Simple math ;)

Macro doesn't evaluate the value (it doesn't add 10 + 10) but simply replaces all it's occurences with the specified expression.